# mongodb namespaces

Tags: database, mongodb, namespaces, nosql

I want to use namespaces(about 15) for every user in project. About 10k user is expected and records in namespaces can reach 2M. Is it ok or I need common collection? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I've taken the 'seperate collection per x' route before and regretted it (and have had to do a lot of conversion work to get away from this).  From my experience it's much better to use one common collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to use separate collection per user, but i don't see a lot of advantages from this.
More information about big number of collections and pros/cons you can find [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections).

But my i opinion is common collection. With common collection you can easy load list of users, without you need to make a lot of requests. Also it become hard to find user that you need through the any UI tool or mongo shell.

But in any way choose what you like more after reading doc above.

Comment: Is it possible to get the records from every collections like if i have user.primary and user.secondary in that collections can i select user by name from both collection at a single time?

Comment: listing all users too easily/by mistake could lead to a security flaw...

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB stores BSON (Binary Interchange and Structure Object Notation) objects in the collection. The combination of the collection name and database name is called a namespace.

For more information, follow the link below:-

http://www.javapedia.net/MongoDB-Interview-questions/1367